# Memcpy and memory management with pcap

Tags: c++, libpcap

as beginner I am having little trouble when dealing with libpcap in c++.
I am aiming to copy contents of 'packet' to another place in memory of equal size, so I can work with it undisturbed.

Here is my code:

```
 string content;
 packet = pcap_next(descr, &header);
 char *packet_copy = malloc(header.len);
 memcpy(packet_copy, packet, header.len);
 for (int i=0; i < (int) header.len; i++) {
        if (isprint(packet[i])) content += packet_copy[i];
 }
```

Ofcourse, this doesn't work. Any help?
Thank you!

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works well for me:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <pcap/pcap.h>

static pcap_t* descr = nullptr;
static pcap_pkthdr header;

int main()
{
    std::string content;
    auto packet = pcap_next(descr, &header);

    // append raw data
    content.append(packet, packet + header.len);

    // append printables only
    std::copy_if(packet, packet+header.len, std::back_inserter(content), 
            [](u_char ch) { return std::isprint(ch); });

    // for C++0x challenged compilers:
    for (u_char const* it=packet; it != packet + header.len; ++it)
    {
        if (isprint(*it)) content += *it;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My compiler is complaining about the printables-only function. "No member named 'copy_if' in namespace 'std'" and "Expected expression".

Comment: `copy_if` was suspiciously missing from C++03.

Comment: @mrkva You're probably using an old compiler. I've added a 'compatibility' version of that piece

Comment: possible :) i work in latest version of XCode, was expecting latest compilers

Comment: @mrkva In that case... did you forget `#include <algorithm>` (and friends)?

Comment: I know. I assumed you know about C++ standard libraries :) Also I neglected to update the whole snippet after I updated with `isprint` filtering. Sorry

Comment: Hey, I have problems with your method actually. The problem is, that sometimes it happens that contents of packet are replaced during the processing for routine (at least that is where I get 'bad access' errors. That is why I wanted to do quick copy of the whole packet and header struct with process which takes less instructions in the system. Maybe I understand it completely wrong though.

Comment: @mrkva Hmm. I only intended to show you how to do the memory management. I had initially 'glossed' over the fact that you were using isspace too. In fact, I know nothing about libpcapc, so everything was "blind". I suggest you stay the deicder of the functionality, as before, and you just pick the memory management techniques that you fancy implementing them :)

Comment: I know, I wrote it also for other people having problems and  reading this :) Thanks a lot for your help.